# Where would Reuven and Gad have been?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, shevatim-12-tribes

The tribes of Reuven and Gad ask Moshe for permission to settle on the east side of the Jordan river. They are granted permission and half of Menashe is placed there as well.

[image: Map]

Is there any way to know where the two tribes would have been situated had they not asked to be placed elsewhere?

Certain places were off limits (since Benjamin and Joseph [cried](https://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/3222/jewish/The-Neck.htm) because they foresaw the destruction of sanctuaries that were going to be in their territories, it must have been ordained that certain territories would be theirs) but the sizes of allocated land must have accommodated the sizes of the tribes - where could the 2.5 tribes have fit?

Which other tribes would have been disadvantaged to make space for these 2.5 tribes?

Comment: What tribe is Shevet Dag?

Comment: @Doniel the same tribe it was last night when I commented on it, after which my comment was deleted...